# fetch some data from two tables

Tags: mysql

i have site like imdb and we provide movie information sin site..and our website have option to rate all movies for every users.

I have two tables
1 . imdb (its for store movie details)
id,name,actors,vote
2. ratings (its for store users rating details)  id,rating_id(its same as id from first table),rating_num,IP

now what am doing is..when anyone rating a movie take the avg of that movie rating by using rating tables (total ratings/number of ratings) and insert that value into "vote" column in first table..my demands this..thats why done like this..

Now my problem is..i want to fetch top rated movies..i mean in vote column which movie have top rating which want to list and one more condition is that that movie should rated by 10 users(use ratings table for that)

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't quite understand how your tables are organized. Is there A) a new row for each rating given by a customer in the ratings table or B) is there only 1 row per movie which is updated?

I am gues it is A and rating_num is the rating given by the costumer.

In this case, a simple MySql solution could make use of aggregate functions such as COUNT and AVG. Untested example.

EDIT - To get the details from the imdb table you will just need to join them.

```
SELECT id as 'ID', COUNT(1) as 'Number of ratings', AVG(r.rating_num) as 'Average rating', i.name, i.actors, i.vote
FROM ratings r
INNER JOIN imbd i ON ( r.id = i.id )
GROUP BY r.id
HAVING `Number of ratings` >= 10
ORDER BY `Average rating` desc
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: its working...but a small problem is i need to get the details of the movie of that top 10 movies from imdb table by using ID..how to do that??